# How do I compile 64 bit SDL code using Code Blocks(Without admin rights)

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks

I am running windows 7 64bit and
I am trying to set up SDL on my school laptop which I do not have admin rights for.
The project compiles fine but when I try to run it I get an error saying " the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)." I Have experienced this error before when trying to run the same 32bit program on my 64bit computer at home. By compiling using 64 bit methods the issue was resovled however I do not have access to a 64bit compiler on my school laptop because I cant find any compilers that don't require admin rights to set up. So If you know of a 64bit compiler download that requires no ADMIN rights to install or if you have an alternate method I would appreciate it.

My stats

Code_blocks 12.11

SDL 1.2.15

SDL_image1.2.10

The compiler that came with codeblocks From Here http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26#windows

codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup_user.exe

Comment: +1 having a simmilar problem with the 0xc000007b error

Comment: Does the school have software that whitelists processes that can run? Maybe you should ask your teacher.

Comment: If you compile a 32bit program and get a 0xc000007b, be sure to have the **32 bit** runtime binary (SDL2.dll) where the .exe is.

Comment: Run your application under debugger

Answer (score 1):

try tdm-gcc: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/

as for 0xc000007b problem:
it may occur when you don't have a working 32bit directx on yout 64bit system, you should update your directx, this may help solve the problem.

directx update: http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=35